# Accessing React component params in event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the best way, but I am trying to access a React component's param in an onMouseOver event handler.

Event handler:

```
  handleTabHover = event => {
    this.setState({ indicatorColor: event });
  };
```

React component:

```
  <LinkTab
    label="Dashboard"
    to="/"
    indicatorColor="gray"
    onMouseOver={this.handleTabHover}
    onFocus={this.handleTabHover}
  />
```

Basically, I'm expecting that `event` in the handleTabHover function to be the `LinkTab` component and then I can access it's "indicatorColor" param to set the class `indicatorColor` state, but that's not the case. I'm new to React and ES6 syntax so I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental to how event handler parameters work.

Comment: you can use event.target.style to get access to all styling attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, I'm expecting that "event" in the handleTabHover function to be the "LinkTab" component and then I can access it's "indicatorColor" param to set the class "indicatorColor" state, but that's not the case.

Yes, You can't do that.

The correct way would be

```
<LinkTab
  label="Dashboard"
  to="/"
  indicatorColor={Colors.Deloitte.Primary.coolGray2}
  onMouseOver={() => this.handleTabHover(Colors.Deloitte.Primary.coolGray2)}
  onFocus={this.handleTabHover}
/>
```

and in your handler will be

```
handleTabHover = indicatorColor => {
    this.setState({ indicatorColor });
};
```

You can read more here. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-or-callback

Comment: Ah, thank you! Just out of curiosity, is there an alternative way to do this that doesn't involve an arrow function/binding in Render? I don't think I'll have any performance issues, but it'd be nice to know of other possibilities.

Comment: The performance cost isn't that big, so you can skip worrying about that part. ;) https://twitter.com/mjackson/status/1006600058228207616
Maybe another way can be using the custom `data-*` attribute if you want. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#example-passing-params-using-data-attributes But not sure if it aligns with what you want to achieve.